# How to create a gridview in asp.net having features similar to the datagridview in Windows forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I understand that the Gridview of asp.net and windows forms are different, but my requirement is that I have a registration form where in a user registers his vehicles.

A single user can have many vehicles, so I want to provide a Gridview with the column names specified and allow users to enter the values in the rows. Depending on the number of vehicles, the user keeps adding them. This task is actually easy in the Windows forms since the grid is in such a way that an empty row is provided by default and we can type in the cells. Finally we can read the DataGridview by each row and save the results to database.

I am looking for this feature in the Asp.net either with the Gridview or any other data control. This looks pretty complex with the asp.net gridview since ill need to work with the edit button, update button for doing this every time and also a add new row button every time.

Is there any other way I can do this task without complexity. I am fairly new to asp.net.

Comment: You can also have a look at 3rd-party controls like the [Telerik Grid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) that has more functionality and good demo page with code.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But sorry I am not looking for a 3rd party control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a new row then what you can do it add a footer row to the gridview. and everytime the user enter information in the footer row you can bind it to gridview and when the page is reloaded you will always have the footer row. This way user can register as many cars they want.